# Is there a difference between an Intel Centrino Duo and an Intel Centrino 2?

Tags: laptop, cpu, thinkpad, dell-latitude

I have 2 old laptops - an IBM ThinkPad Z61t and a Dell Latitude E6500.  The ThinkPad has an Intel Centrino Duo and the Latitude has an Intel Centrino 2.  The Latitude has significantly better performance not due to RAM, so I'm wondering if the processors are different, but I thought they were the same.  The question is: are they different, and are they compatible?

Pictures of the stickers on the laptops below.

[image: centrino duo]
[image: centrino 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two different generations of of Intel's Centrino line of processsors. The Centrino Duo was the earlier iteration and the Centrino 2 is the successor to the Centrino Duo.

The Centrino Duo processors came with a 800MHz front-side bus and CPU clock speeds up to 2.4GHz. The Centrino 2 processors had an improved 1,066MHz front-side bus and were available with CPU clock speeds up to 3.06GHz.

Centrino Duo and Centrino 2 processors are not compatible in that the are supported by different sockets. 
The sockets supported by Centrino Duo are PBGA479 and PPGA478.
The sockets supported by Centrino 2 are BGA479 and PGA478.

Comment: Whoops forgot part of the question hold on while I edit

Comment: I'm asking if I replace the centrino duo with the centrino 2 will it work?

Comment: Centrino refers to the *entire* platform - chipset, processor and even wifi. The processors are pentium Ms or various families of core processors.  You probably want to check what these processors are, and look up their specs. for example, the z61 has chips spanning at least 2 generations of core processors, and has a core duo and core 2 duo option according to thinkwiki http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:Z61t